# Moving items from one listbox to another listbox through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, listbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkaxt.jpg)I am trying to move items from one list to another on checkbox check but actually 1st list are select options and checked property is not coming in jquery , can anybody help how to achieve this ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Once a field selected / deslected, update UI List
  $('#GridFields').bind('change', function(option, checked, select) {
    var selectedval = $('#GridFields option:selected').last().val();
    if ($('.sort-selected li[field-id="+selectedval+"').length > 0) {
      $('.sort-selected').remove(selectedval);
    } else {
      $('.sort-selected').append('<li class="list-group-item" field-id="' + $(this).find(':selected').last().val() + '">' + $(this).find(':selected').last().text() + '</li>');
      $('.sort-selected').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".sort-selected")[0].scrollHeight
      }, 1000);
    }
    enableSort();
  });
```

```css
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control input-sm multiselect" id="GridFields" multiple="multiple" name="GridFields" style="display: none;">
<option disabled="disabled" value="Remedy_Short_ID">Request ID</option>
<option value="Actuals_Per_Day">Actuals Per Day</option>
</select>
<div class="btn-group open" style="width: 100%;"><button type="button" class="multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Request ID, Summary, Request Category, Product Name, Comp Progress Level" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;" aria-expanded="true">
<ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu" style="-ms-overflow-x: hidden; -ms-overflow-y: auto; max-height: 300px;"><li class="multiselect-item filter"><div class="input-group input-group-sm">

--First Five Elements

<li class="disabled active"><a tabindex="-1"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="Comp_Progress_Level"> Comp Progress Level</label></a></li>

--Remaining Elements
<li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="Actuals_Per_Day"> Actuals Per Day</label></a></li>


</ul>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Layout Columns", "Layout Columns", new { @class = "form-label" })  @Html.ListBox("GridFields", CommonEntities.getGridFieldsMultiList(), new { @class = "form-control input-sm multiselect"})
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="panel panel-custom1">
  
    <div class="panel-heading">Display Order (Drag n Drop an Item)</div>
    <ul class="list-group sort-selected" style="height:276px;overflow-y:auto">
      <li class="list-group-item disabled" field-id="">Request ID</li>
      <li class="list-group-item disabled" field-id="">Summary</li>
      <li class="list-group-item disabled" field-id="">Request Category</li>
      <li class="list-group-item disabled" field-id="">Product Name</li>
      <li class="list-group-item disabled" field-id="">Comp Progress Level</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan Why u downvoted?

Comment: Your .net code obviously won't run in the client side snippet, please update your code to create a working snippet that isolates your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, following should work :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Once a field selected / deslected, update UI List
  $('#GridFieldsWrap input[type=checkbox]').bind('change', function() {

    $('#GridFieldsWrap input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       
        if ( $(".sort-selected li[field-id=" + $(this).val() + "]").length==0) {
          $('.sort-selected').append('<li class="list-group-item" field-id="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).parent().text() + '</li>');
        }
      } else {
        $(".sort-selected li[field-id=" + $(this).val() + "]").remove()
      }
    })

    $('.sort-selected').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".sort-selected")[0].scrollHeight
    }, 1000);
  })
  //enableSort();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="form-group" id="GridFieldsWrap">
    <ul id="GridFields">
      <li class="disabled active"><a tabindex="-1"><label class="checkbox"  ><input type="checkbox" value="Request_ID" checked> Request ID</label></a></li>
      <li class="disabled active"><a tabindex="-1"><label class="checkbox" ><input type="checkbox" checked value="Summary"> Summary</label></a></li>
      <li class="disabled active"><a tabindex="-1"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" checked value="Request_Category"> Request Category</label></a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="Product_Name"> Product Name</label></a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="0"><label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="Comp_Progress_Level"> Comp Progress Level</label></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="panel panel-custom1">
    <ul class="list-group sort-selected" style="height:100px;overflow-y:auto">
      <li class="list-group-item disabled" field-id="Request_ID">Request ID</li>
      <li class="list-group-item disabled" field-id="Summary">Summary</li>
      <li class="list-group-item disabled" field-id="Request_Category">Request Category</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1389597/mike-t How to remove items, i am able to add to 2nd list but not able to remove from it. I tried this `        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            //add selected to the bottom
        }
        else {
            //remove selected item from list.

        }`but not helping

Comment: You want to move the items both ways? from top list to bottom, and also from bottom to top?

Comment: Yes both ways , but from 1st list it should show only selected and move to  2nd list . While un-selecting from 1st list by checkbox it should remove from second. As these are list options i am not getting property of Checked.

Comment: i understand now what you want, please see my updated snippet. In my example you need to hold CTRL to select more items at once

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1389597/mike-t I have added image in question if it helps

Comment: only one item we can see in 2nd list now and moreover it is not removing while un-check, not working. Can we add checkbox checked property to 1st list so in jquery we can use that.

Comment: it really depends on how is your select component generated - you haven't posted the html code generated by your .NET component. I assumed it's select[multiple], that's what i used in my working example. In order to help you please update your post with the HTML that is produced by your .NET code

Comment: i updated my example using checkboxes, please try now

Comment: updated HTML code in question. I have updated for first element(disabled) and remaining one element (active) in 1st list.

Comment: please see the updated code snippet, it works with the same HTML markup from your example

Comment: also , i don't see any element with id GridFields in your posted HTML code - in order for my code to work, make sure you wrap your select list with element with this id

Comment: I have edited my snippet with total HTML code, but still your answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: GridFields in Jquery doesn't have the property checkbox, so it not not going inside the function.

Comment: add id GridFieldsWrap to your first `<div class="form-group">`  and try my updated code  ->  `<div class="form-group" id="GridFieldsWrap">`

Comment: Almost working, but we are emptying 2nd list after every change so we are losing the order.Can we preserve the order by any chance?

Comment: glad it works now. Please accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: the answer is still not accepted, please click on the "check" icon under votes count next to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Adding `id="GridFieldsWrap"` on the form level helps you to get the checkbox property checked.

In List options if you want, checkbox property checked, please try to add one level above the id property and check there if checkbox property appears.